# How do you draw a line in MQL4 like the plot() function in Tradingview?

Tags: plot, line, draw, mql4

I have a variable that changes on each candle and want to plot it as a line while running a back-test in MQL4.  I tried HLine but it just does a horizontal line which shifts on each candle but just shows whatever it's value was on the latest candle.  I would like to plot the variable's value on each candle with a dot or a line like these lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJnPP.png

Comment: `ObjectCreate(0,name,OBJ_TREND,...)` for line between two points. If you need to draw rectangle (that is on your chart) - use `OBJ_RECTANGLE` or `OBJ_RECTANGLE_LABEL`

Comment: Is there a way to just draw points?  Like once per candle (I have a function that executes once per candle already) could I just draw a dot somewhere on each candle?  They don't need to connect really, just need dots at accurate prices.

Comment: I got it to kind of work, but i'm not sure on accuracy yet:

 ObjectCreate(name,OBJ_TEXT,0,Time[0],currentHigh[0]);
   ObjectSetString(0,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,".");
   ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clrRed);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_ANCHOR,ANCHOR_CENTER);

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this..

Comment: Okay got it working with wingdings using OBJ_ARROW, but the symbol is a little low

Comment: that is ok, wingdings allow nice pictures. I would suggest to check the return from `ObjectCreate()` - it returns bool and if false- no need to go further. In you want to have larger objects - use `ObjectSetInteget(0,name,OBJPROP_STYLE)` to enlarge or `OBJPROP_FONTSIZE`

Comment: Right now the only problem is they are too low.  I have it set to put a dot at the High of the previous candle (High[1]), as you can see in this screenshot they are a bit lower than High[1]   https://i.imgur.com/KJXPWXh.png

Comment: probably something is wrong with your logic, show a MCVE to go further